# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have probed numerous questions and documentation on this error and cannot seem to find where I am going wrong. The error is on this line:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`flutweets`.`refs`,    
CONSTRAINT `refs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `tweets` (`id`))
```

The database is MySQL, and I am using Workbench to inspect it; I also know that all the database engines are InnoDB and the Row Formats are Compact. I have three tables: tweets, hashtags, and references.
Here is where I create the tables:

```
tweets Table

Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + TWEETS_TABLE + "("
                + TWEETS_ID + " BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                + TWEETS_TIME + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_USER + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_TEXT + " VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                + TWEETS_LOCATION + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_CITY + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_PROVINCE + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_COUNTRY + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_TIME_ZONE + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_LATITUDE + " DECIMAL(20,16),"
                + TWEETS_LONGITUDE + " DECIMAL(20,16),"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (" + TWEETS_ID + ")"
                + ")");
       . . .

hashtags Table

Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + HASHTAG_TABLE + "("
                + HASHTAG_ID + " BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                + HASHTAG_TEXT + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_ID + " BIGINT NOT NULL,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (" + HASHTAG_ID + ")," 
                + "FOREIGN KEY (" + TWEETS_ID + ")"
                + "REFERENCES " + TWEETS_TABLE
                + "(" + TWEETS_ID + ")" 
                + ")");
      . . .

references Table

Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + REF_TABLE + "("
                + REF_ID + " BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                + REF_TEXT + " VARCHAR(255),"
                + TWEETS_ID + " BIGINT NOT NULL,"
                + "PRIMARY KEY (" + REF_ID + ")," 
                + "FOREIGN KEY (" + TWEETS_ID + ")"
                + "REFERENCES " + TWEETS_TABLE
                + "(" + TWEETS_ID + ")" 
                + ")");
```

Here are the statements I use to insert and the methods to insert them (I am using prepared statements):

```
/* INITIALIZE PREPARED STATEMENTS */

// Tweets
private static final String TWEETS_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " + TWEETS_TABLE
        + " (" + TWEETS_TIME + ", " + TWEETS_USER + ", " + TWEETS_TEXT + ", " + TWEETS_LOCATION + ", " + TWEETS_CITY + ", " + TWEETS_PROVINCE + ", "
        + TWEETS_COUNTRY + ", " + TWEETS_TIME_ZONE + ", " + TWEETS_LATITUDE + ", " + TWEETS_LONGITUDE + ")"
        + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
private PreparedStatement tweetsStatement;

// Hashtags
private static final String HASHTAGS_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " + HASHTAG_TABLE
        + " (" + HASHTAG_TEXT + ", " + TWEETS_ID + ")" + " VALUES(?,?)";
private PreparedStatement hashStatement;

// References
private static final String REF_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " + REF_TABLE
        + " (" + REF_TEXT + ", " + TWEETS_ID + ")" + " VALUES(?,?)";
private PreparedStatement refStatement;
```

public void insertHashtag(FluTweet tweet, int hashIndex, Integer tweetID) {

```
    // Pull all of the Hashtag's relevant elements.

    String hashText =  tweet.getHashtag(hashIndex);

    try {
        hashStatement.setString(1, hashText);
        hashStatement.setString(2, tweetID.toString());

        //INSERT HASHTAG INTO TABLE
        hashStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void insertReference(FluTweet tweet, int referenceIndex, Integer tweetID) {

    // Pull all of the Reference's relevant elements.

    String refText =  tweet.getReference(referenceIndex);

    try {
        refStatement.setString(1, refText);
        refStatement.setString(2, tweetID.toString());

        //INSERT REFERENCE INTO TABLE
        refStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I have no idea why this is not working, any help would be much appreciated. Like I said, I have probed numerous other posts and cannot find relevant help.

Comment: which row throws the exception?

Comment: The error is stated at the very beginning of my question. And for the row, immediately throws this error as soon as my main class starts to insert tweets into the database. So basically right away. I believe that this has all the information necessary to fix the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that there is an existing row in the `tweets` table where the `tweets_id` matches the `tweets_id` in the `references` row that you are trying to add? The error message is telling you that you are trying to add/update a child record (in `references`) for which no parent record (in `tweets`) exists.

Comment: See my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 5):

**Background**

I found out the answer to my own question. It was never a problem with any of the actual database handling. It turns out, when I was passing the id to be used as the foreign id in hashtags and references, I was getting my id from a counter in the main class; where every new tweet had a number that went with each hashtag and reference for that tweet that would later be used as a foreign key. That foreign key would reference the primary key in the tweets table, which auto increments.

**Here was the problem:**

It turns out that MySQL is **NOT** zero-indexed when you auto-increment; where the first value is zero, then one, then two, etc. Instead, it starts at one. So when I tried to reference the primary key with the foreign key, the counter that started at zero for every tweet that I assigned (the foreign key) was being incorrectly matched to the auto incrementing tweet id in the tweets table (primary key).

Therefore, I was always off by *one*.

I hope this helps anyone that may have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

if we didn't set valid child class object primary key value then we can see the **MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException**.if we ignore the primary key value of child class object then based on the configurations set in hibernate pojo/hbm.xml files first level cache(session) will flush it into data base.